# hsl color problem in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hsl

I am trying to declare the border of a div using hsl() like this:

```
border: 2px solid hsl(0,200,105);
```

I am using Firefox 3.5 and there is no border being rendered at all. The same code works perfectly if hsl() is replaced with rgb()

I read somewhere that Firefox supports hsl() and hsla()

Am I doing something wrong?

and if hsl() is not supported, does anybody have any code to convert hsl to rgb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color), the syntax should be:

```
hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
```

Here's a nice tutorial on [Working with HSL in CSS](https://monc.se/kitchen/119/working-with-hsl-in-css), and a [useful converter](http://monc.se/kitchen/stew/hsl/).

Comment: I think the passive aggressive 'first google result' comment is unnecessary!

Comment: the year is 2022, and now this page IS the first google result for "border color hsl not working"

Comment: @andy - good point, thanks! Also a good opportunity to rephrase that and make the answer nicer.